# Why HTML form not working with <button> tag?

Tags: php

Contents of my index

```
        <form id="contactus" action="mail.php" method="POST">
          <input type="text" name="fname" id="name" placeholder="Your name"><br>
          <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Phone"><br>
          <div class="mybtn">
              <button type="submit" value="submit" form="contactus" class="button">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </form>
```

And mail.php

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['fname'];
    $phone=$_POST['phone'];
    $formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $phone";
    $recipient = "email@gmail.com";
    $subject = "Email header";
    mail($recipient,$subject, $formcontent);
?>
```

But it doesnt seem to work, i am not receiving any emails.

When I try only `mail($email, $header, $content)` I do receive a message so it's only not working with the form.

EDIT: I checked mail.log file and I there's no record of the email going out.

EDIT 2: Found out the problem. It was the `<button>`. When I changed it to `<input type="submit">` it' started working. Though I have no idea why it is not working with `<button>`.

Comment: whats the error display? or error log?

Comment: @Efx no error, i just don't receive emails.

Comment: is you error reporting enabled? you can check @Qirel 's link

Comment: How did you get email@gmail.com?  Must have been an early adopter.

Comment: @Efx Yes it's enabled. Still no errors.

Comment: @RightClick I just put it here for demonstration purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The problem i see here is that the 'message' variable and 'from' variable are not separated by comma. 
so the proper way to have written the code should be

```
mail($recipient, $subject, $message, 'From: anyname you want');
```